# toBinaryString type error

Tags: java, string, compiler-errors, int

I am getting an incompatible types error when compiling the following:

```
public class E10_Bitwise {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Bit b = new Bit();
        int x = 87;
        int y = 170;
        x = Integer.toBinaryString(x);
        y = Integer.toBinaryString(y);
        b.combiner(x, y);
    }
}
```

For some reason it thinks x and y, inside the parentheses, are strings. Am I making an error or is something else going on here?

```
E10_Bitwise.java:22 error: incompatible types
                 x = Integer.toBinaryString(x)
                                           ^
required: int
found: string
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Return type of [toBinaryString()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toBinaryString%28int%29) is String.

Try,

```
String xStr=Integer.toBinaryString(x);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to assign a return value of type `String` to a variable of type `int`. This will not work.

You need to assign the return value of `toBinaryString`, like this:

```
String xStr = Integer.toBinaryString(x);
String yStr = Integer.toBinaryString(y);
b.combiner(xStr, yStr);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to assign a `String` (which Integer.toBinaryString()) returns back to `int x`.

You will need a String variable to assign it to instead.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know Java at all but it looks like you're trying to assign a **string** (the result from the Integer.toBinaryString() call) to an **int** (x, y).

My guess is that toBinaryString() creates a binary string (eg. "010101110") representation of an integer.